# How to replace spaces and pipe with commas

Tags: jquery, replace

I have some strings that are separated with `|`(space pipe space) and I would like to replace them with commas. I tried this below but it's giving me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

```js
var string = 'This is my | string I want to replace';
string.replace(' | 'g, '/,/ ');
console.log(string);
// Desired output:
// This is my, string I want to replace
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's all incorrect syntax, read up on how to write RegEx in JS.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I did read up on RegEx in JS, that's how I came up with the attempt shown above.

Comment: @user13286 But if you look at the docs for `replace` . you'll see that the regex is the *first* parameter, that an immediate regex in JS is surrounded by `//` (not single quotes), and the examples that use regex have the parameters in the right place. http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace That's what we mean by "due diligence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up many things.

If you want `g` then you should use a regex--what you show isn't valid JS:

```
...replace(/ | /g, '/,/ ')
```

Once you use a regex, you need to escape the `|`:

```
...replace(/ \| /g, '/,/ ')
```

Then specify the string you want to replace it with, which you show with slashes in the code, but don't mention it in the post:

```
...replace(/ \| /g, ', ')
```

Since `replace` isn't in-place, you need to save off the result:

```
const s2 = string.replace(/ \| /g, ', ')
// s2 = "This is my, string I want to replace"
```

Sometimes reading documentation actually *does* help.

(Noting that depending on input you might actually want to split and join with `,` instead.)